# PHP: sub TIME from DateTime

Tags: php

I have: $worked_hrs_today = 07:18
`$worked_hrs_today = $usr_stamp_in->diff($usr_stamp_out);`

I have: $shift_break = 00:30:00
`$shift_break = $shift_data['break'];`

`07:18` is a DateTime obj, or maby it's called interval?
`00:30:00` is a string.

How can i convert `00:30:00` to a interval, so that i can sub that time from `07:18`?

What i wan't is to calculate: `07:18 - 00:30 = 06:48`

Should i use: new DateTime();

Comment: no, use `DateInterval` if you want to substract it from a `DateTime` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its a DateTime obj. just use strtotime()

Like this:

```
$shift_break = strtotime($shift_break);
$newTime = $worked_hrs_today - $shift_break;
```

Comment: So if i eco $shift_break i get: 1524522600  How to i handle this?

Comment: I found this: echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($shift_data['break']));